# Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied

Tags: java, ant, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I am working on a desktop application which is using eclipse-rcp plug-ins, Currently my application is running on Java 1.8_162 with eclipse 4.6.0 (Neon) , and using Apache Ant 1.9.9 to build the application. We are planning to upgrade this application to run on OpenJDK 11.0.2+9_ version, hence we set JAVA_HOME and env. variable to point JDK 11. After all set, we are facing the following issue during ant build. Please help me on this.

```
 init:
 [java]
 [java] generateScript:
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript] Some inter-plug-in dependencies have not been satisfied.
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript] Bundle org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide:
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Unsatisfied import package org.apache.lucene.document_[7.1.0,8.0.0).
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Unsatisfied import package org.apache.lucene.index_[7.1.0,8.0.0).
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Unsatisfied import package org.apache.lucene.search_[7.1.0,8.0.0).
 [java] [eclipse.buildScript]       Unsatisfied import package org.apache.lucene.store_[7.1.0,8.0.0).
```

Comment: Eclipse Neon based code is not going to work with Java 11 because of changes to the JRE layout and the Java 9 module code. You need to use the current Eclipse 2019-03 for that.

Comment: Yes, I tried with latest eclipse 2019-03. But now it throws some packages are missing. Bundle org.apache.batik.util.gui_1.8.0.v20170214-1941 failed to resolve.:
     [java]     Unsatisfied import package org.apache.batik.util.gui.resource_1.8.0.
     [java]     Unsatisfied import package org.apache.batik.util.resources_1.8.0.
     [java]     Unsatisfied import package org.apache.batik.xml_1.8.0.

Comment: Each release has different required plugins, you need to update your build to specify the correct list

Comment: Ok, let me check. Thank you @greg-449 :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like plugin `org.eclipse.epp.logging.aeri.ide` is specifying a range of acceptable versions for various `org.apache.lucene.xxxx` plug-ins (at least version 7.1.0 and less than version 8.0.0).

Presumably the plugins in the new Eclipse don't meet those version requirements (or are missing altogether). You will need to find a compatible set of these plugins.

Comment: Thank you Greg, I am still struggling to find the latest/right versions which meets my requirement.

Comment: I have edited my question which explains more about what error I am facing exactly. Can you please help me on this? @greg-449